# AWS Marketplace Integration - .NET Core AmazonAWSMarketplaceMeteringClient - ResolveCustomer not authorized

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core

I am having an issue resolving the customer using the registration token provided on post redirect. When I attempt to resolve the customer, I get an exception saying the user is not authorized.

"Amazon.AWSMarketplaceMetering.AmazonAWSMarketplaceMeteringException: 'User is not authorized to call ResolveCustomer for this product.'"

**I build the client like this:**

```
 marketplaceClient =
                     new AmazonAWSMarketplaceMeteringClient(awsCredentials, regionEndpoint);
```

**and the AWS policy for the user I used to build the client is the following:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "MarketplacePolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aws-marketplace:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Finally I attempt to resolve the customer like this:**

```
var customerData = await marketplaceClient.ResolveCustomerAsync(resolveCustRequest).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Here is a screen cap of the VS exception:

[Visual Studio Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqelL.jpg)

Any and all help/ideas as to why this isn't working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

**The API needs to called from the seller account id used to publish the SaaS application to successfully resolve the token.**

The correct marketplace account was communicated to me and everything works as it should.